# Android AutoCompleteTextView not working

Tags: java, android, search-suggestion

I've been trying to implement a simple suggestion list in my app, I'm using the AutoCompleteTextView but I'm facing a problem, the suggestions are not showing up. All solutions I've read online don't seem to work neither.
Here is my code:

```
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBank);
    listOfBanks = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.banks);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfBanks);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help please

Comment: This seems fine to me !! Try removing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as this is not needed since your string array is same at all times.

Comment: @SachinAggarwal Still not working

Comment: Please post more code or debug the code to find the exact bug location. This seems fine to me.

Comment: I've figured out the problem using a regular string worked for me other than getting the String Array from xml